# Is there a linear sorting algorithm given an oracle that finds kth smallest item?

Tags: algorithms, sorting, oracle-machines

Given a machine that can compute the kth smallest item of an Array A in $O(\sqrt n)$ time. Find a recursive function that can sort A in linear time corresponding to $n$ which is the length of A.

First I tried to optimize some of the sorting algorithms I knew using this new property but the best I could do was $O(n^{3/2})$ and currently I'm wondering whether if it is possible or not.

Comment: I can see where you are going but coming up with the algorithm is where im having problems with.

Comment: Already asked: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/131623/using-a-special-given-machine-find-a-recursive-function-that-can-sort-a-in-linea

Comment: Can you credit the source where you encountered this task, to help others find it by search?

Comment: @Dmitry I'm not sure what you have in mind, but I doubt that it works. You can already find the median in $O(n)$, even without the special oracle, but this still only results in an $O(n\log n)$ sorting algorithm.

Comment: In fact, consider the following wide class of algorithms: find the elements at ranks $\theta_1 n,\theta_2 n, \ldots, \theta_k n$ (where $k = O(\sqrt{n})$); partition the original array into subarrays; recurse. If $\theta$ is the corresponding distribution $\theta_1-0, \theta_2-\theta_1, \ldots, 1-\theta_k$, then partitioning takes roughly time $H(\theta) n$, and the length of the array reduces by a factor of $e^{H(\theta)}$ on average. If $\theta$ is constant, this means we need $\log n/H(\theta)$ steps, for a total running time of $n\log n$.

Comment: @Dmitry You also have to split the elements in the array according to whether they are smaller than the median or larger than the median.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus, you are right, sorry. I've also noticed that we are allowed to do queries for A, not for subarrays of A.

Comment: @Dmitry If so, a simple information-theoretic argument rules out a linear time algorithm: we can only run $\sqrt{n}$ special queries, and each gives us only $\log n$ bits of information, out of the requisite $\Theta(n\log n)$. Each comparison only gives us one more bit, which is not enough. Therefore, I suspect that we can use the oracle on arbitrary arrays. This is also the only way in which a recursive approach makes sense.